# If $A=\{1,3,5,\ldots\}, B =\{2,4,6,\ldots\}$, then $|A|=|B|=|A\times B|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How can I prove cardinality of cross product for infinite sets?

The problem is:

> If $A =\{1,3,5,7,9,...\}$, $B =\{2,4,6,8,... \}$, then $|A|=|B|=|A\times B|$.

Need solution for this statement.

Comment: what is the  meaning of the equality in $ \mid A \mid = \mid B \mid = \mid A \times B \mid$ ?

Comment: @terori ya. but my question is about the equality. that equality means there exists a bijection between them no?

Comment: so ultimately we have to find bijections between, $A$ and $B$, and between $A$ and $A \times B$.

Comment: @GA316 I mistook the your comment is related to the notation of formulas.

Comment: $tetori me too not good at English well :).

Answer (score 1):

To show two sets have the same cardinality you should find a bijection from one set to the other.

Can you find a bijection from $A$ to $B$?

If you want, you can even do this by finding a bijection of each of these sets with $\mathbb{N}$ since both sets are countably infinite.

Can you then find a bijection to show that the cardinality of $A\times B$ is the same?

From the above, this is really just showing that the cardinality of $\mathbb{N}$ is the same as that of $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ which is a very standard argument.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Prove that $\Bbb{|N\times N|=|N|}$.

Answer (score 0):

Other hint: Every member of $A$ is of the form $2n+1$, while every member of $B$ is $2n+2$. This should give you an idea of how to define a bijection between the two sets.